# My DTO object is NOT being saved in the database via the data context why?

Tags: mvvm, ria, converters, dto

i am working on a project and we are using MVVM and Wcf ria services. because of the headache posed by foreign keys whose description must be displyed in grids on UI, i had to resort to using dtos that do the work of joining queries from different tables and returning the descriptions.

now the problem is tha when i want to save and i use context.attach(entity) after editing, the error message comes up saying an object with this identity already exists. i tried detaching before attaching and its still same thing no changes.

can sombody help me out? thanks in advance.

charles.

Comment: I deleted my answer. It was for NHibernate, not EF. Sorry about that.

Comment: I am so sorry i did not inclde that fact in my question. Sorry for the mix up Dan!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd do something like this:

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
var myEntity = db.Entities.Single(x=>x.Id = dto.Id);
myEntity.Value = dto.Value;
db.SaveChanges();
```